# JavaFX Custom control does not appear in Scene

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller, custom-controls

I started to learn JavaFX for couple of days. I took a lot of stackoverflow examples, google-it, youtube videos, and all seems good in examples, but mine does not work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
So, I make tests only for now, nothing important, it is not an application in real world.

I've built a Custom Control using SceneBuilder, so this is the fxml file for it:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="cControl" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0"
            style="-fx-border-color: #111111; -fx-border-radius: 2; -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 50% 0% to 50% 100%, #f0f0f0, orangered); -fx-background-radius: 2;"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            >
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnClickMe" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="67.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickMeAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="8.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblTitle" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" focusTraversable="false" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Label" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="56.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The model is this:
PackTestModel.java

```java
package com.myapp.customcontrols;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class PackTestModel {
    public PackTestModel(String labelText) {
        setLabelText(labelText);
    }

    public String getLabelText() {
        return labelText.get();
    }

    public StringProperty labelTextProperty() {
        return labelText;
    }

    public void setLabelText(String labelText) {
        this.labelText.set(labelText);
    }

    private final StringProperty labelText = new SimpleStringProperty();

}
```

This is the controller:

```java
package com.myapp.customcontrols;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class PackTestController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button btnClickMe;
    @FXML
    private Label lblTitle;

    private final PackTestModel packTestModel;

    public PackTestController(PackTestModel ptm) {
        packTestModel = ptm;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        lblTitle.textProperty().bind(packTestModel.labelTextProperty());
    }
}
```

This is the code for my CustomControl class:

```java
package com.myapp.customcontrols;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PackTestCC extends AnchorPane {

    private PackTestController packTestController;

    public PackTestCC(PackTestModel model) throws IOException {
        super();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PackTest.fxml"));
        packTestController = new PackTestController(model);

        loader.setController(packTestController);
        try {
            Node n = loader.load();
            this.getChildren().add(n);
        }catch (RuntimeException e){}

    }
}
```

And my main application Main.java file looks like this:

```java
package com.myapp;

import com.myapp.customcontrols.PackTestCC;
import com.myapp.customcontrols.PackTestModel;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main extends Application {
    private MainController2 mainController;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Fonts/DINOTBold.otf"), 16);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main-view2.fxml"));

        mainController = new MainController2();
        fxmlLoader.setController(mainController);

        Parent n = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(n, 800, 600);
        mainController.getAnchorPane().getChildren().add(new PackTestCC(new PackTestModel("This is for test")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinWidth(800);
        stage.setMinHeight(600);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

main-vew2.fxml is very simple, as long as it is for tests:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane
        fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0"
        style="-fx-border-color: #111111; -fx-border-insets: 5;"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

and this is MainController2 class:

```java
package com.myapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController2 implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }

    public AnchorPane getAnchorPane() {
        return anchorPane;
    }
}
```

The Custom Control must look like this, according to SceneBuilder UI:

[image]

but, when I run my application, all I see is only the border from main-view2.fxml:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing here?

Comment: I copied your code and it worked for me (I saw the control as expected).  The only changes I made were to delete the line which loads a font because the font was not supplied (it is not needed for this test anyway).  And to delete the attribute from PackTest.fxml `onAction="#onClickMeAction"` because no such event handler exists in the corresponding controller code.

Comment: That is very strange. So it means I have a problem with my development environment?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to IntelliJ settings. I made a new project, added those files to this project run it and everything works. But my initial project which I started this question, it is a Maven project, so I think there are some problems with this. Some settings which I don't find out, I know it is a modular project, modules are "opens" and "exports" in `module-info.java` file, so I don't know what to set up. I think I will start from scratch, on non-Maven or Gradle, with actual configuration in IntelliJ.

Comment: When I created a project with your sources, I used the Idea [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) to create a new modular Maven JavaFX project, then copied in your sources, made the changes noted and ran the app.  I did not manually configure the project execution, modify the generated module info or use a JavaFX SDK.

Comment: I've started a new project from scratch and now it works... Seems something was wrong in that project, I don't know what as long as I didn't have any errors.